# Sum values from a list, selected by another list

Tags: python, list

I have data of team names and scores:

```
Team A  9,
Team A  13,
Team B  24,
Team C  6,
Team A  15,
Team B  10,
Team C  19,
Team A  30,
Team B  5,
```

But the information is stored in 2 lists:

```
List_team = ['Team A', 'Team A', 'Team B', 'Team C',
             'Team A', 'Team B', 'Team C', 'Team A', 'Team B']

List_score = [9, 13, 24, 6, 15, 10, 19, 30, 5,]
```

I need the sum of Team A’s score and Team B’s score.

Maybe to sort them after zipping the 2 lists is a first step.

What’s the best way to find out?

Comment: what you have tried?

Comment: Would you be open to an answer that uses NumPy? Of course you can do this without it, but if you have NumPy available, there is a very quick way to filter and sum lists..

Comment: @David Z, thanks for the idea. Because I need the elements to be in further calculations so a direct way may be the best choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one way to do that, with a dictionary:

```
teams = {}
teams_and_scores = zip(List_team,List_score) #this will pair each team with their score

for team, score in teams_and_scores:
    if team in teams:
        teams[team] += score #add score if team is already in dictionary
    else:
        teams[team] = score #add team to dictionary with their score
```

Using your example:

```
>>> List_team = ['Team A', 'Team A', 'Team B', 'Team C', 'Team A', 'Team B', 'Team C', 'Team A', 'Team B']
>>> List_score = [9, 13, 24, 6, 15, 10, 19, 30, 5,]
>>> teams = {}
>>> teams_and_scores = zip(List_team,List_score) #this will pair each team with their score
>>> for team, score in teams_and_scores:
    if team in teams:
        teams[team] += score #add score if team is already in dictionary
    else:
        teams[team] = score #add team to dictionary with their score


>>> teams
{'Team A': 67, 'Team B': 39, 'Team C': 25}
>>> teams['Team A']
67
```

Comment: thanks for the help. adding the notes makes it a very reader friendly answer. a question, how to know if I only need a specific team's score?

Answer (score 2):

Use a `defaultdict`, which will populate a dictionary entry with the given key and a default value if it doesn't yet exist:

```
import collections
List_team = ['Team A', 'Team A', 'Team B', 'Team C', 'Team A', 'Team B', 'Team C', 'Team A', 'Team B']
List_score = [9, 13, 24, 6, 15, 10, 19, 30, 5]
result = collections.defaultdict(list)
for k, s in zip(List_team, List_score):
    result[k].append(s)
```

You can then do any number of things with these data, such as passing a value to `sum()`:

```
>>> sum(result['Team A'])
67
```

Comment: thanks for the great answer. it's the most straight forward! it's very difficult not to choose yours but hope you don't mind as you have many scores...

Comment: @MarkK - The idea is to pick the best answer, regardless of reputation.

Comment: yours and the other are the same good to me so that's why I said "it's very difficult not to choose yours..." if the system allows 2 best answers, certainly yours is the No. 1 best.

Comment: @MarkK - You've just made it that much harder for users who look at this question to find the "No. 1 best." Please base your votes/accept on the quality of the answer, not on the user who answered.

Comment: thanks for the guide. yours' most practical. El'endia Starman's most readable for newbie like me because it provides notes. So I choose El'endia Starman's.

Answer (score 2):

```
In [9]: result = {}

In [10]: for x in enumerate(List_team):
    ...:     result.setdefault(x[1], 0)
    ...:     result[x[1]] += List_score[x[0]]
    ...:     

In [11]: result
Out[11]: {'Team A': 67, 'Team B': 39, 'Team C': 25}
```

or

```
In [15]: result = {}

In [16]: for x, y in zip(List_team, List_score):
    ...:     result.setdefault(x, 0)
    ...:     result[x] += y
    ...:     

In [17]: result
Out[17]: {'Team A': 67, 'Team B': 39, 'Team C': 25}
```

Comment: thanks for the very good lines. hope you don't mind I choose another for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
List_team = ['Team A', 'Team A', 'Team B', 'Team C', 'Team A', 'Team B', 'Team C', 'Team A', 'Team B']
List_score = [9, 13, 24, 6, 15, 10, 19, 30, 5]
df = pd.DataFrame({'Team': List_team, 'Score': List_score})
df1 = df.groupby('Team').sum()

In [47]: df1
Out[47]:
        Score
Team
Team A     67
Team B     39
Team C     25
```

Comment: thanks. it's a great one. just I need the results separately. hope you don't mind I choose another for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Using a comprehension to populate a default dict set to zeroes, and then populating it position by position. Other solutions may be more idiomatic, but this one seemed most human.

```
List_team = ['Team A', 'Team A', 'Team B', 'Team C', 'Team A', 'Team B', 'Team C', 'Team A', 'Team B']

List_score = [9, 13, 24, 6, 15, 10, 19, 30, 5]

scores = { x : 0 for x in List_team }

for idx,team in enumerate(List_team):
    scores[team] += List_score[idx]

print scores # all scores
```

Result:

```
{'Team A': 67, 'Team C': 25, 'Team B': 39}
```

Update: Get just one team's scores at a time:

```
print scores['Team A'] # Just Team A
```

Result:

```
67
```

Comment: thanks. it's a great one. just I need the results separately. hope you don't mind I choose another for the answer.

Comment: Not at all! Glad you enjoyed it.

Comment: After thinking about it, I don't really understand what you mean by "need the results separately". Can you clarify?

Comment: I mean, for example I need "Team A"'s score only.

Comment: OK @mark-k, I've added an example showing how scores can be retrieved from my answer by team.

Comment: marvelous! thanks for the work. your spirit is a sunshine to society. carry on! (hope I can choose multiple best answers)

Answer (score 1):

This is based on TigerhawkT3's answer, I just find better to use int instead of list for the defaultdict.

```
import collections
List_team = ['Team A', 'Team A', 'Team B', 'Team C', 'Team A', 'Team B', 'Team C', 'Team A', 'Team B']
List_score = [9, 13, 24, 6, 15, 10, 19, 30, 5]
result = collections.defaultdict(int)
for k, s in zip(List_team, List_score):
    result[k] += s
```

*result* would give back `{'Team A': 67, 'Team B': 39, 'Team C': 25}`

No need to sum lists here.